# Kafka panics Hyperledger fabric orderer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hyperledger-fabric

I am getting this error in orderer logs:

```
2018-05-31 19:22:31.010 IST [orderer/consensus/kafka] try -> DEBU 2a3 [channel: testchainid] Need to retry because process failed = kafka server: The requested offset is outside the range of offsets maintained by the server for the given topic/partition.
```

Due to this error write operations on blockchain is not happening.

If anyone knows anything about this error please let me know

Answer (score 2):

I only saw this error when I was testing what could break my network or put it in an inconsistent state.

From what I experienced, it is linked with the Leader Kafka Broker serving the topic at an offset lower than what the Orderer was expecting. I could create the error by either hard resetting the Kafka Brokers, so they were fresh, but the Orderer and rest of the network was not. Or by hard reseting the Zookeepers so when requests came in from consumers and producers (the Orderer) they treated it as a new Topic and potentially assign the Leader Broker to a broker that was not up to date for that topic.

I'm not sure of how your network entered that state but I'm pretty sure that error is to do with the **Orderer asking for an Offset at a value higher than what the Leader Kafka Broker has for that Topic**. Basically like an index out of range error for an array.

Since I was just experimenting, to fix the problem I just restarted the entire network fresh (deleting all data persistence).

Comment: I can not delete all the data if it is a live application. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of how you reached that error but you could potentially rolling hard reset all your orderers. It all depends on if you can confirm your Kafka Brokers are actually up-to-date with all the transactions. I think you can confirm that by spinning up a new orderer. The new orderer will start from offset 0 on all your channels and catch up to your current orderers, or at least the last "stable" point. If that state is OK I think you can hard reset your actual orderers and they will do the same. Check the block number the new orderer gets to and compare it with the orderers and peers

Comment: Oh also, confirm which broker is the leader broker for the Topic testchainid, and then compare its log with the logs of the other brokers in your cluster. Make sure the leader broker has the same or most up-to-date log.